# How I change jQuery datatables default row count shown

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Datatables has 4 sizes of records to show: 10,25,50,100. I just want table show 15 records as default.
am doing this but this is not work for me

```
"aLengthMenu": [ 15, 25, 50, 100 ],
```

and

```
"iDisplayLength": 15
```

Comment: You will need to search through the code (and HTML) for the value of 10 and change it to 15.

Comment: hiii, @jeff am also try this but jquery error occur

Comment: The error is the reason, you are doing it right and it _will_ work when you have corrected your error(s)

Comment: @davidkonrad, the point is how i corrected this error

Comment: Yes - but the error has nothing to do with the code above, that can I tell. Besides that no one can guess what error you have and how you correct it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put the entire contents of aLengthMenu property(ordenation and values)

try this:

```
"aLengthMenu": [[15, 25, 50, 100], [15, 25, 50, 100]],
"iDisplayLength": 15
```